# Apache camel alternative in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, apache-camel

Apache Camel provided the sort of configurable architecture which allows web service messages to be determined dynamically during run time for web services that are hosted in Java environment.

I was wondering whether there is a similar/equivalent framework for applications written in c# and hosted in .Net/SharePoint environment?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? There must be a MS alternative to Camel or a third party product that fills this niche.

Comment: There is no alternative just get over the hump and use Camel today.

Answer (score 4):

A bit late to this party, but might be of use to some people...

This wiki page has a list of alternatives - or it lists Camel as one of the options - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_business_integration_software

Which leads me to suggest BizTalk - but that may be over the top for your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Apache Camel has not been ported to any other language. In a sense, there is no reason to port it. The whole point of Camel is Enterprise integration. All it really does is route and process messages.

If you need it to interact with a Sharepoint or .NET application, you can define a Camel Endpoint for whatever messaging or transport system you are using.

What problem are you trying to solve? I dont really know what you mean by:

> allows web service messages to be determined dynamically during run
>   time

The messages arent determined dynamically... whatever that means. Camel provides an implementation of many Enterprise Integration Patterns (EIP), but it needs to know the type of whatever message it is routing.

Camel has hundreds of automatic conversions, so it may seem like magic, but the truth is that jsut like anything else in Java, everything within Camel is type safe.

Comment: I would like to point out that due to vm design and implementation details most things in java are far from type safe

Answer (score 2):

The only. Net alternative is biz talk but that is probably over the top for your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

There is no port of Apache Camel to .NET or any other platform afaik. I am also not aware of any plans for that. It wouldn't be a trivial effort. Camel interacts with a bunch of systems, via supporting a large number of protocols.

Camel runs well on Windows, so you can have it running as a Java process (or remotely on any OS). If you need SharePoint integration, you can implement a SharePoint Service module to interact with the Camel instance.

Answer (score 1):

In Azure you can use [Azure Data Factory](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/data-factory/#overview).